# Device not registering for push notifications

Tags: parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I successfully added the parse framework and code to my app! I tried it on a simulator and no "Would you like push notifications..." window popped up.
So, I tried it on my iPhone 5 testing device on iOS 8.1, same thing. The notification enrollment popup NEVER pops up. :( Help!

Comment: You should use new API for device with iOS8 and later.

Comment: @KudoCC can you elaborate? I am new to parse and coding and am considered a "noob."

Comment: Can you post the code that register the remote notification?

Comment: Use `registerUserNotificationSettings:` for iOS8 and later and `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` for the devices before iOS8.